# How to add additional python modules when using AWS Glue Studio Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I tried to include additional python modules when using AWS Glue Studio

I followed below document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/notebook-getting-started.html

The code I ran:

```
%idle_timeout 2880
%glue_version 3.0
%worker_type G.8X
%number_of_workers 15
%additional_python_modules sqlalchemy==1.4.45, psycopg2-binary==2.9.5, awswrangler==2.18.0, smart_open[s3]
```

However, when I tried to import after that, all modules still got ModuleNotFoundError.